# Rasterizing a scatterplot in Python

Tags: python, raster, scatter-plot

I am trying to rasterize the following scatterplot in Python. I want to separate it to boxes of dimensions 100x100. Is it possible to do it in Python? I have done something similar in the past in QGIS, but I thought of using python this time and doing it on a graph instead of a map.

[image]

Comment: note that to most developers, "rasterizing" means turning something into a "raster image", which is what a PNG images are.  maybe you could find a better term to use?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the grid function of Matplotlib. It would be helpful to provide an code example.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)


major_ticks = np.arange(0, 2000, 8)
minor_ticks = np.arange(0, 2000, 100)

ax.set_xticks(major_ticks)
ax.set_xticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(major_ticks)
ax.set_yticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)

# Or if you want different settings for the grids:
ax.grid(which='minor', alpha=0.2)
ax.grid(which='major', alpha=0.5)
```

If you provide an example I can show you how to write it without ticks

To answer the comment: 
It depends on the way your data is formatted. If it is a simple pandas dataframe you could do something as follows:

```
points_a = df[(0 >= df['x'] > 100) & (0 >= df['y'] > 100) ]
```

This gives you all points in the raster from 0-100 and you could do something similar for every raster.

Answer to second comment:

```
import random
df_index = df[(0 >= df['x'] > 100) & (0 >= df['y'] > 100) ].index
shuffled = random.shuffle(df_index)
new_list = shuffled[:50]
half_point_a = points_a[points_a.index in new_list]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and then do you have an idea on how to take the values of each box and work with the separately?

Comment: It is in pandas dataframe. I would like for each box in this grid to drop half the observations randomly.

Comment: You can save the indexes to a list, random shuffle the indexes and drop the first half, last half or every other element. various ways. But in the end the random shuffle should be enough

Comment: Thank you, I will try my best I am new at coding so I am not sure of how to do it. If you have some time, please write some code or provide any useful links. Otherwise thanks for your help!!

Comment: vassilis if @Mibi's answer helped you, you could mark it as the correct answer to help future askers with similar issues.